# Formulate a function that takes lists T and R and a threshold temperature Q and returns a list of timestamps where Q was exceeded

Tags: python

Assume you have a sensor that reports temperature readings periodically. The readings are stored as 2 lists of equal length; List T composed of timestamps for each reading and list R composed of temperature readings for each of the matching timestamps. Your goal is to identify timestamps at which a certain threshold temperature Q was crossed.

Formulate a function that takes lists T and R and a threshold temperature Q and returns a list of timestamps where Q was exceeded. Note that you should only return timestamps representing a datapoint that crosses the threshold, and ignore those that remain above the threshold.

Sample input:

```
>> T = [1460545900, 1460545910, 1460545920, 1460545930, 1460545940, 1460545950] 
>> R = [0, 7, 12, 18, 8, 17]
>> Q = 10
```

Sample output

```
>> [1460545920, 1460545950]
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Any code that you did and need help with ? SO is not to get your Homework done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification is a little ambiguous, hence I'll propose you two slightly different solutions, choose the one you like the best.

```
>>> T = [1460545900, 1460545910, 1460545920, 1460545930, 1460545940, 1460545950]
>>> R = [0, 7, 12, 18, 8, 17]
>>> Q = 10
>>> [t for r0, r1, t in zip(R, R[1:], T[1:]) if r0*r1+Q*Q < Q*(r0+r1)]
[1460545920, 1460545940, 1460545950]
>>> [t for r0, r1, t in zip(R, R[1:], T[1:]) if r0*r1+Q*Q < Q*(r0+r1) and r1>r0]
[1460545920, 1460545950]
>>>
```

We have a transition around `Q` when `(r0-Q)×(r1-Q)<0` — expanding the product it is `r0×r1+Q²-Q(r0+r1)<0` or `r0×r1+Q²<Q(r0+r1)`.

If you want to keep only upward transitions, you have to check if the second temperature is larger than the first.

Probably a better solution:

```
>>> RQ = [r-Q for r in R]
>>> [t for rq0, rq1, t in zip(RQ, RQ[1:], T[1:]) if rq0*rq1<0 and rq0<0]
[1460545920, 1460545950]
>>>
```